# radio.write () siempre devuelve 0

Tags: c++, arduino

```
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <RF24_config.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#define TAMMSJ 10

RF24 radio(9,10);


const uint64_t pipe = 0xE8E8F0F0E1AA;

char  msj[TAMMSJ];

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  radio.begin();

  radio.openWritingPipe(pipe);
  radio.setRetries(3,5);
}

void loop() {
   if(Serial.available() > 0){
     String data = Serial.readString();
     data.toCharArray(msj,data.length());
     if(!radio.write(msj, data.length())){
      Serial.println("Mensaje no enviado");
    }
    else
      Serial.println("Mensaje enviado");
   }
}
```

Me esta pasando que la primera vez que transmito un dato se manda y recibe correctamente, pero luego `radio.write()` siempre me devuelve 0.
Me falta algo que no estoy teniendo en cuenta?

Comment: `msj` acepta únicamente 10 caracteres ¿Estás seguro de que no desbordas ese buffer?